# How to change background color of mat-form-field only in disabled mode?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to change the background color of the mat-form-fields on for those who are disabled. By after a good look I cannot figure how to do it. Below is my code for the same:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Verified by</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="verby">
    <mat-error>Hint</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
form = this.fb.group({
  verby: [{value:'',disabled:true}]
});
```

And in the **style.css** I have changed like this:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline:disabled .mat-form-field-outline:disabled {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

But this thing is not taking any affect. Any way anyone can suggest ?

Comment: Do you want the input field to disable?

Comment: yes it's already disabled no issue with that but not able to change color of it

Comment: try this `mat-form-field input:disabled{background: #ccc;}`

Comment: nope not working

Comment: add `disabled` in `<input matInput formControlName="verby" disabled="disabled">` and then try css  Its working for me you check here https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/wvWxrdM

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-form-field{
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Also you can force css to apply using ::ng-deep for e.g.

```
::ng-deep.mat-form-field{
  background-color: gray !important;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.css)

**Updated** [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-form-field-on-select-value-bqtbvf?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.css)

```
.mat-input-element:disabled {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: I want it on mat-form-field disabled not in normal state

Comment: I've tried but this is not perfect please see the stackblitz url you shared I have put mat-form-field's appearence as outline. There the whole area is not color which I actualy want